# Casting int to char pointer: unexpected value?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting int pointer to char pointer causes loss of data in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208566/casting-int-pointer-to-char-pointer-causes-loss-of-data-in-c)

What is the reason for the output being `64` in the following code?

```
void main()
{
    int i=320;
    char *ptr=(char *)&i;
    printf("%d",*ptr);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're only getting the lower byte - (320-256) = 64.

Comment: Can you please explain why you subtracted 320 from 256?

Answer (score 2):

Implementation defined; depends on the endianness and sizeof(int) on your platform. You basically truncate your int to the first byte of itself which is apparently its least significant bit on your system.

320 = 0x00 00 01 40
and by truncating to char which is always one byte:
0x40 = 64

That's why.

Edit: as Daniel Fischer pointed out, this also depends on `CHAR_BIT` being <= 8 (which it is in most, if not all, systems nowadays).

Comment: For completeness: it also depends on `CHAR_BIT`. If `CHAR_BIT >= 9`, on little-endian machines, it should give 320. Now, where do I find the next implementation with `CHAR_BIT > 8`?

Comment: I think no modern systems use a non-octet `char`.

Comment: I think so too. But there are still a few old machines with 36-bit words in use, so it's not yet merely an oddity of the standard.

Comment: Of course, the C standard is very well thinked so is the language.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `char` pointer. So it points to *one byte*. 320 does not fit in one byte.

Answer (score 0):

320 is 0x0140

64 is  0x0040

You're only reading the lower byte of the int value.

Answer (score 0):

The memory associated with `i` points to an integer (i.e. greater than one byte) value of 320 or `0x0140`.

You then take a pointer to this integer and cast it as a pointer to a `char` (a single byte).

Then you print the value at this address, in this case `0x40`, i.e. the LSB. This is your value of 64.

In other implementations, you would get the MSB, which would be `0x01` or a value of 1.