# c casting pointer of type int* to char* and then accessing the value

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Could somebody explain why the output value of this code is 64?

`&a` gets the address of a, it yields a pointer of type `int*`. This pointer of type `int*` is then cast to a pointer of type `char*`. Then you access the value at the address stored in `ptr`.

I know it is related to `sizeof(char) == 1`, but I just can't quite see how the output is 64.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

   int a = 320;
   char *ptr;
   ptr =( char *)&a;

   printf("%d ",*ptr);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably some relevant reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208566/casting-int-pointer-to-char-pointer-causes-loss-of-data-in-c

Comment: The `60` in the end of the question have confused me very much. Change it to `64` as in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

That's because a `char` has 8 bits (one byte) and an `int` can have 32 or 64 bits (4 or 8 bytes) depending on your system

I speak in terme of bits because the explanation here needs some understanding in how data is represented in your machine. This line :

```
int a = 320;
```

your `int a` here needs more than a byte to store its value since it's larger than 255 so it will store it in 2 bytes. 320 in binary is

```
00000001   01000000
   ^          ^   
 byte #2 | byte #1
```

so when you cast the `int*` to `char*` and access the first element pointed you get the first byte : `01000000` which equals 64. If you tried to access the second element of the char* you would find the value `1`

Comment: nice, but not quite true.   One consideration is if the underlying architecture is BIT Endian or LITTLE Endian..  A second consideration is this line: `int a = 320`  will always allocate `sizeof(int)` bytes regardless of the value being stored.  So, if the underlying architecture had be the 'other' Endian, then the printed value would have been 0